# Вылетает CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache2

Завершается работа на знаке ">" без разницы в каком месте, встречает этот знак и завершается. Возможно проблема в настройке php или самого codeigniter прим

```
class Person_model extends CI_Model {
var $table = 'users';
var $column_order = array('fio','phone','abon_adr', null); //set column field database for datatable orderable
var $column_search = array('fio','abon_adr'); //set column field database for datatable searchable just firstname , lastname , address are searchable
// var $order = array('fio' =>"вылетает здесь" 'asc'); // default order 

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->"если убрана предыдущая строка 'вылета' то тут"load->database();
}
```

Лог ошибки:

> ( An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException Message: /var/www/html/site/www/application/models/Person_model.php exists, but doesn't declare class Person_model Filename: /var/www/html/site/www/system/core/Loader.php Line Number: 306 Backtrace: File: /var/www/html/site/www/application/controllers/Person.php Line: 9 Function: model File: /var/www/html/site/www/index.php Line: 292 Function: require_once

Comment: Логи в студию. Экстрасенсы в отпуске

Comment: Если вы в другом месте вызвали `load->database()`, то просто уберите её из класса `Person_model`. Эту функцию вызываю один раз.

Comment: Дело в том что я это уже как-то решал. Вот только забыл как :( 

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: RuntimeException

Message: /var/www/html/site/www/application/models/Person_model.php exists, but doesn't declare class Person_model

Filename: /var/www/html/site/www/system/core/Loader.php

Line Number: 306

Backtrace:

File: /var/www/html/site/www/application/controllers/Person.php
Line: 9
Function: model

File: /var/www/html/site/www/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once@ArchDemon

Comment: По хорошему, создают класс `CI_My_Model`, который на следует от `CI_Model`, а следующие модели, наследую от `CI_My_Model`, в этом классе и вызывают `load->database()`

Comment: Да маленькая "ремарка" я просто перенёс с одного виртуального хоста на другой на старом всё работало. И вот столкнулся с такой проблемой, менял разве что данные подключения и базовый урл. @KostaB.

Comment: Гугл подсказывает: проверьте таги файлов php `<?`, должно быть `<?php`

Comment: @KostaB. по хорошему `load database` пишут в автозагрузчике.

Comment: @Manitikyl есть разные варианты хорошего =)